# on mouse hover in button open tab

Tags: javascript

I have buttons and with them, whenever I do onmouseover I want to open the content that shows the info for that button. Can someone guide me through?

This is how I am opening the content on mouseclick:

```
function openTab() {
    var content     = $(this).parent().next(".content"),
        activeItems = wrapper.find(".active");

    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).add(content).add(activeItems).toggleClass('active');
        wrapper.css('min-height', content.outerHeight());
    }
};

tabToggle.on('click', openTab);
```

I tried to interact directly with onmouseover, but no success.

```js
// ----------------- Variables

wrapper   = $(".tabs");
tabs      = wrapper.find(".nav-tab");
tabToggle = wrapper.find(".tab-toggle");

// ----------------- Functions

function openTab() {
 var content     = $(this).parent().next(".content"),
  activeItems = wrapper.find(".active");
 
 if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).add(content).add(activeItems).toggleClass('active');
  wrapper.css('min-height', content.outerHeight());
 }
};

// ----------------- Interactions

tabToggle.on('click', openTab);

// ----------------- Constructor functions

$(window).load(function(){
  tabToggle.first().trigger('click');  
});
```

```css
  .tabs .content { 
    width: 70%;
    opacity: 0;
   }

  .tabs .content.active {  
    opacity: 1; 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

<div class="tabs">
  <div class="nav-tab">
    <button class="tab-toggle">Tab 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="heading">Tab 1 Content</h3>
    <p class="description">Lorem  ratione quasi deleniti neque rem, recusandae. Tenetur mollitia optio possimus fugiat cumque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-tab">
    <button class="tab-toggle">Tab 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="heading">Tab 2 Content</h3>
    <p class="description">Lorem  cumque.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit 1: And how can I let one tab open when initializing the page?

Comment: Did you mean `tabToggle.on('mouseover', openTab);`?

Comment: thats it, I was using onmouseover, so a dumb mistake.  @Brian  what if I want my first tab to be open whenever I start the page? what should I do?

Comment: tabToggle.first().trigger('mouseover');

Answer (score 0):

Should be: `tabToggle.on('mouseover', openTab);`

```js
// ----------------- Variables

wrapper   = $(".tabs");
tabs      = wrapper.find(".nav-tab");
tabToggle = wrapper.find(".tab-toggle");

// ----------------- Functions

function openTab() {
 var content     = $(this).parent().next(".content"),
  activeItems = wrapper.find(".active");
 
 if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).add(content).add(activeItems).toggleClass('active');
  wrapper.css('min-height', content.outerHeight());
 }
};

// ----------------- Interactions

tabToggle.on('mouseover', openTab);

// ----------------- Constructor functions

$(window).load(function(){
  tabToggle.first().trigger('click');  
});
```

```css
.tabs .content { 
    width: 70%;
    opacity: 0;
   }

  .tabs .content.active {  
    opacity: 1; 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

<div class="tabs">
  <div class="nav-tab">
    <button class="tab-toggle">Tab 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="heading">Tab 1 Content</h3>
    <p class="description">Lorem  ratione quasi deleniti neque rem, recusandae. Tenetur mollitia optio possimus fugiat cumque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-tab">
    <button class="tab-toggle">Tab 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="heading">Tab 2 Content</h3>
    <p class="description">Lorem  cumque.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```